# Building a dynamic form using PHP

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have a laravel based admin.

I'm looking for a PHP library which will help me to build dynamic forms.

By dynamic forms - I mean for example, when the user checks a radio button - new options will appear.

I can build one form using the basic laravel form builder and jQuery.
The thing is - I may have hundreds of such forms, I don't want to build each one of them manually.

Storing them in some kind of model which will be translated to a form is what I'm looking for.

Can you think of a PHP lib which will help me to achieve what I'm looking for?
Are there any other practices ?
All the form builders I've found are good for basic static forms.

Many thanks.

Amir

Answer (score 1):

This is not done by PHP. This is work for JavaScript because you don't want to reload page with every click. You can use some framework like AngularJS or simple AJAX.

AJAX tutorial : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/
AngularJS tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/

Comment: PHP libs can also create Js code. Having a js lib would also help.. angular is quite overkill for my needs. Thanks for helping.